# No source available error in accessing shared library

Tags: c++, eclipse, shared-libraries, ubuntu-14.04

I have two project in my Eclipse IDE. My OS is Ubuntu. One is application project and another one is shared lib project. I have linked all paths and libs requirement as discussed in the [link](http://linuxtortures.blogspot.sg/2012/02/shared-libraries-with-eclipse.html). But when I debug, I got error as `No source available for "0x0"`. The error happened at `iOCR* pOCR = (iOCR*)create();` when I access the shared library object. What is wrong with my linking?
My shared library codes and application codes are attached.

Shared library header file

```
#ifndef OCR_DLL_H_
#define OCR_DLL_H_    
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <tesseract/baseapi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Define.h"    

using namespace cv;   

namespace VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM {
    class iOCR{    
        public:
            virtual ~iOCR(){}
            virtual int preProcessing(Mat &img) = 0;
            virtual int textExtraction(Mat &img) = 0;
    };    
    class OCR : public iOCR{    
        public:
            OCR(){}
            ~OCR(){ ; }
            int preProcessing(Mat &img);
            int textExtraction(Mat &img);
        private:    
    };    
}   

#endif /* OCR_DLL_H_ */
```

Shared library cpp

```
#include "OCR_dll.h"   

namespace VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM {
    extern "C" iOCR* create_object(){
        iOCR *p = new OCR();
        return p;
    }

    extern "C" void destroy_object( iOCR* object )
    {
      delete object;
    }

    int OCR::preProcessing(Mat &img){


        return SUCCESS;
    }

    int OCR::textExtraction(Mat &img){


        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Application main.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "OCR_dll.h"

#define SUCCESS 0
#define FILE_ERROR 1
#define HTTP_ERROR 2
#define THREAD_ERROR 3

using namespace VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM;
using namespace cv;

void *readImage(void *ptr);
void *postHTTP(void *ptr);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     // on Linux, use "./myclass.so"
      void* handle = dlopen("OCR.so", RTLD_LAZY);

      iOCR* (*create)();
      void (*destroy)(iOCR*);

      create = (iOCR* (*)())dlsym(handle, "create_object");
      destroy = (void (*)(iOCR*))dlsym(handle, "destroy_object");

      iOCR* pOCR = (iOCR*)create();

      if(pOCR){

          destroy( pOCR );
      }//if(pOCR)

      dlclose(handle);
      return 0;
}
```

I checked with objdumb and the output is as follow

```
cdc@cdc-desktop:~/workspace/OCR/Debug$ objdump -TC libOCR.so

libOCR.so:     file format elf32-i386

DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.1.3 __cxa_atexit
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              __gmon_start__
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              _Jv_RegisterClasses
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 operator delete(void*)
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::ios_base::Init::Init()
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 std::ios_base::Init::~Init()
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
00000000  w   D  *UND*  00000000              _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
00000000      DO *UND*  00000000  CXXABI_1.3  vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  CXXABI_1.3  __cxa_pure_virtual
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBCXX_3.4 operator new(unsigned int)
00000000      DO *UND*  00000000  CXXABI_1.3  vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info
00000000  w   DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.1.3 __cxa_finalize
00000c95 g    DF .text  00000020  Base        destroy_object
00000dc4  w   DF .text  0000001e  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR::~OCR()
00000de4 g    DF .fini  00000000  Base        _fini
00000d94  w   DF .text  00000030  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR::~OCR()
00000d94  w   DF .text  00000030  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR::~OCR()
00000d4c  w   DF .text  0000001e  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::iOCR::~iOCR()
00000cc0 g    DF .text  0000000a  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR::textExtraction(cv::Mat&)
00000d78  w   DF .text  0000001c  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR::OCR()
00000aec g    DF .init  00000000  Base        _init
00000e40  w   DO .rodata    00000020  Base        typeinfo name for VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR
00000d78  w   DF .text  0000001c  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR::OCR()
00003018 g    D  .bss   00000000  Base        __bss_start
00000d26  w   DF .text  00000025  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::iOCR::~iOCR()
00000d6a  w   DF .text  0000000e  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::iOCR::iOCR()
00000d26  w   DF .text  00000025  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::iOCR::~iOCR()
0000301c g    D  .bss   00000000  Base        _end
00000e18  w   DO .rodata    00000018  Base        vtable for VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::iOCR
00000e30  w   DO .rodata    0000000c  Base        typeinfo for VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR
00000d6a  w   DF .text  0000000e  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::iOCR::iOCR()
00000cb6 g    DF .text  0000000a  Base        VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR::preProcessing(cv::Mat&)
00000e00  w   DO .rodata    00000018  Base        vtable for VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::OCR
00003018 g    D  .data  00000000  Base        _edata
00000e84  w   DO .rodata    00000008  Base        typeinfo for VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::iOCR
00000c6c g    DF .text  00000029  Base        create_object
00000e60  w   DO .rodata    00000021  Base        typeinfo name for VIDEOANALYTICS_PLATFORM::iOCR
```

Comment: In your actual code, you *do* have error checking? I.e. making sure that `dlopen` or `dlsym` doesn't fail?

Comment: start by listing symbols from OCR.so file, using "objdump -TC OCR.so" and make sure create function shows up. you might be missing dll_export

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: how to check dlopen and dlsym don't fail?

Comment: Read [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).

Comment: @sramij, yeah I did objdumb and I don't see create function. objdumb result is updated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible problems that I see.

The first is, and for this I'm only guessing, that you put the shared object in the same path as the executable loading the shared object, and thought that `dlopen` would look in the process current directory. [The manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) says that

> If filename contains a slash ("/"), then it is interpreted as a (relative or absolute) pathname.  Otherwise, the dynamic linker searches for the library as follows...

And then it lists where the function will look for the shared object, which includes e.g. `/usr/lib`.

If the library is not in the path that `dlopen` looks in, then the shared object will not be found.

The simple solution to this first problem is to use an absolute or relative path instead, e.g.

```
dlopen("./OCR.so", RTLD_LAZY);
```

This will look in the process current directory (which might not be the same directory as where the executable program is).

The second problem is that you named the shared object `libOCR.so`, and you ask `dlopen` to look for `OCR.so`. The `dlopen` does not automatically add the `lib` prefix when looking for files, you need to provide the actual file-name of the shared object.

Comment: Thanks, let me test and will get back to you.